# Does appendix have to be on new page?

Tags: supporting-information

I have perhaps a weird question. I'm preparing my paper for a conference (ACML, if that matters) and am just over the page limit (inclusive of appendix and references). At the moment, there's a page break between references and appendices. Is it acceptable to have no page break between the main text, references and appendices?

As far as I know, the conference's official instructions are not detailed enough to say whether appendix needs to be on its own page. In fact, the latex template provided by the conference have everything on a single page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answered your own question in your last sentence. The latex template is the one that you are supposed to be using, so its output is mandatory. You can also look at papers from previous conferences.

If ACML is the Machine Learning conference, it will follow the typical CS and the typical Springer guidelines which will not have a page break between references and appendices.

There are all sorts of tricks to make a paper a little bit shorter. You can start looking at your write-up. Most people have fluff in their writing that can be removed, things like "We note that A does B to C." which can be reduced often to "A does B to C". You can look at your figures and tables.

TLTR: Use the conference latex template and do not have a page break.